# jQuery hasClass after using toggleClass

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to check if an item has a class if that class has only just been added via using toggleClass. The below code is not working. What's the best solution to do this with.

```
$('.feature-filter').click(function () {

    $(this).toggleClass('feature-filter-selected');
    var category_list = [];
    $('.feature-filter').hasClass('feature-filter-selected').each(function () {
        var category = $(this).attr('id');
        category_list.push(category);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) returns Boolean(`true`/`false`) result depending on the class name present on the element. You cannot chain/use jQuery methods on it.

To select elements having both classes, use

```
$('.feature-filter.feature-filter-selected')
```

You can use [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/).

```
$('.feature-filter').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('feature-filter-selected');

    var category_list = $('.feature-filter.feature-filter-selected').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get();
});
```